# Check this typecasting in C++

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

Help me in correcting this.  I want the answer as 123 only, but it shows some insane outputs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[] = "123 234 435 - ";
    int i = 0;
    int b[100];
    int j = 0;
    while (a[i] != ' ')
    {
        b[j] = a[i] - '0';
        j++;
        i++;
        //  cout<<b[j]<<endl;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k<j; k++)
    {
        cout << b[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: In your last loop: `cout << b[j];` should be `cout << b[k];`

Comment: You print `b[j]` instead of `b[k]`, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The notes as comments below

```
// initialization of b[0] is required
while (a[i] != ' ')
{
    b[j] = a[i] - '0'; // what about higher digits? a 10*b[i] is missing
    j++; // why? b[0] is not over yet
    i++;
    //  cout<<b[j]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insane outputs ?

You are doing :

`b[j] = a[i] - '0'`

`a[i]` when `i = 0` is `1` so ascii of `1`(49)- ascii of `0`(48) = 1
so the character corresponding of ascii goes into `b[j]`(and similarly for others i and j values) and thus you get some confusing characters and not 123 , for 123 you just need to put `b[j] = a[i]` .

Also note that in the printing loop you should have `cout << b[k]`.